# Async Population of Angular Autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend

Currently I have a function that grabs an array of Category[] objects from an API, the Category model looking like this:

```
class CategoryModel {
    constructor(
        public id: number,
        public title: string,
        public clues_count: number,
    ) { }
}

export {CategoryModel};
```

We use the API like this:

```
  populateCategories() {
    this.api.getCategories$()
    .subscribe((response)=>{
        this.category = response;
    });
  }
}
```

this populates a variable called `category: CategoryModel[];`

I have an auto populate angular object that looks like this and grabs from the category variable:

```
      <form class="example-form">
        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Category..." aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
          <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let cat of category | async" [value]="category">
              {{cat.id}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-autocomplete>
        </mat-form-field>
      </form>
```

Is there a way to populate this even though the category variable is populated in an async fashion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Async pipe can only work with promises or observables.

So if you do it like so it should work:

Add a public field into your component:

```
categories$ = this.api.getCategories$()
```

And replace category with categories$ like in example below:

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let cat of categories$ | async" [value]="category">
```